# Number theory: if $(a,b)=1$, show that $(ac,b)=(c,b)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Mostre que, se $(a, b) = 1$, então $(a · c, b) = (c, b)$

Como posso fazer isso usando

$(a,b) = 1\implies$ Existem $m,n$ naturais tais que
$am - bn = 1$

**Tentative translation:**

> Show that if $(a,b)=1$, then $(ac,b)=(c,b)$.
>
> How can this be done using
>
> $(a,b)=1\implies$ there exist natural numbers $m,n$ such that $am-bn=1$?

Comment: It's in Portuguese.  The translated content is as follows: Show that if $(a, b) = 1$, then $(ac,b) = (c,b)$.  How do I show that $(a,b) = 1 \rightarrow$ there exists some natural numbers such that $am - bn = 1$?

Comment: Can someone read this? http://w3.math.uminho.pt/site/files/historicooutros/1617_Numeros.pdf

Comment: The *ã* and the *-em* inflection on *Existem* clearly mark it as Portuguese.

Comment: For this problem, you will need to apply division algorithm to get to $(ac,b)$ and then, to $(c,b)$.

Comment: Someone who actually reads Portugueses should check my tentative translation, but I’m pretty confident that it’s correct.

Comment: @frogeyedpeas: it is OK to ask in any language. Someone will translate for you. Please see http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/1619/630 for more information.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: It is easy to show that $(c,b)\mid(ac,b)$. To show that $(ac,b)\mid(c,b)$, let $d=(ac,b)$.

- Prove that $(a,d)=1$. (Use the fact that $d\mid b$.)
- Now use the fact that $d\mid ac$ to prove that $d\mid c$. Here is where you can use the fact that there are natural numbers $m$ and $n$ such that $am-dn=1$: multiply the equation by $c$.

Answer (score 1):

Solve $am-bn=1$ and $cu-bv=(b,c)$. Then replace $u$ with $u\cdot 1=u\cdot(am-bn)$ and re-arrange. You should be able to get an expression $$(ac)X+bY=(b,c)$$